# reactJs Jest:`jsdom 4.x onward only works on io.js, not Node.jsT:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

package.json:

```
 {
   "name": "flux-pricing",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Pricing component with flux",
   "main": "js/app.js",
   "dependencies": {
      "flux": "^2.0.0",
      "jest-cli": "^0.5.0",
      "jsdom": ">= 0.1.23 < 4.0.0",
      "react": "^0.12.0",
      "underscore": "^1.7.0"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
      "browserify": "~6.2.0",
      "envify": "~3.0.0",
      "react": "^0.12.0",
      "reactify": "^0.15",
      "watchify": "~2.1.0",
      "gulp": "~3.8.9",
      "gulp-browserify": "~0.5.0",
      "gulp-concat": "~2.4.1",
      "node-jsx": "~0.2.0",
      "express": "~4.0.0"
     },
     "scripts": {
        "start": "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d .",
        "build": "browserify . | uglifyjs -cm > js/bundle.min.js",
        "test": "jest"
    },
   "jest": {
     "rootDir": "./js"
   },
  "browserify": {
     "transform": [
         "reactify",
         "envify"
       ]
   }
```

}

after npm install when i try to do npm test [image]

s\jsdom\lib\jsdom.js:3
`jsdom 4.x onward only works on io.js, not Node.jsT: https://github.com/tmpvar
^
Unexpected token ILLEGAL
how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you done any research whatsoever? *Note that as of our 4.0.0 release, jsdom no longer works with Node.js™, and instead requires io.js. You are still welcome to install a release in the 3.x series if you use Node.js™.*

Comment: @BenFortune I have used "jsdom": ">= 0.1.23 < 4.0.0"  in package.json file to overcome that problem. But it is not working. what is the correct way to include version 3.0 of jsdom. because jest-cli refers jsdom internally . How to change that?

Comment: `npm install --save jsdom@3.1.2`

Comment: @BenFortune It requires lower version of node . I am currently using 0.12 while this one requires node to be 0.10. Downgrading Dom does not seem to be good choice

Comment: It doesn't require it, `0.10` is the *minimum* requirement and downgrading jsdom is your *only* choice if you don't want to use io.js.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The solution is to switch to use Jest 0.4 instead.

Here's the issue from github.
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/469#issuecomment-133105627

I actually had to downgrade to Jest 0.3 and node 10.x to get the Jest React example working. Here's the reference
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/427